# Mod_rewrite to direct subdirectory to another URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http, mod-rewrite

I am trying to play with Apache Mod_rewrite and I cant get this to work.

I want to redirect

xyz.com/blog to xyz.wordpress.com

I edited the .htaccess file to add this line.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ http://xyz.wordpress.com/$1 [NC]
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://xyz.wordpress.com/$1 [NC]
```

Also don't forget to add

```
RewriteEngine on
```

on top of RewriteRule.